# Flask SQLAlchemy Operational Error Access Denied for User

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Can't connect to db.

Username and password is correct. I've tried several combinations. I've verified my `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` using `'mysql://user:pass@localhost:8889/db-name'` but cannot connect. I can connect without issue using mysql command line utility. I've even tried using a username without a password to no avail.

**Flask App Details - config.py**

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

CSRF_ENABLED = True

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://datadmin:password@localhost:8889/db-name'
WHOOSH_BASE = os.path.join(basedir, 'whoosh')
```

**_*init*_.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import basedir

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views, models
```

**Stacktrace**

```
File ".../site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'datadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") None None
```

**Connecting via Command Line**

```
user@hostname:~$ mysql -u datadmin -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.5.29 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Anybody have any tips or know how I can figure out what's wrong?

Comment: There isn't enough details. Please add the complete stack trace of the error and also provide a copy of a session that shows what command line arguments you use to access from `mysql`. Of course you can replace the real password with a fake one.

Comment: Check that mysql is running. What OS are you using? What is the error message? Please add more information in order for us to help you

Comment: MAMP on OSX 10.7.5. MySQL is running because I can interface ithe the mysql command line utility at the same time as well as access phpmyadmin.

Comment: I've added some more details. Let me know if you need something else and thank you for the help!

Comment: can you do `use db-name` on the client? You are showing you can connect to MySQL but not connect to the DB.

Comment: yes. I can access the db.

Comment: @frankV u, sir. This very line:
    `WHOOSH_BASE = os.path.join(basedir, 'whoosh')`
saved my life. In case anyone is reading this. I had this bug in which a query to whoosh would go:
    `SELECT (...) FROM (...) WHERE null`
I specified `WHOOSH_BASE` the way you did and voilá, my text search works again. Thank you with all my eternal soul love.

Answer (score 2):

On your Flask app you are connecting through port 8889.

On the mysql command line, however, you seem to be using default options, which in a stock mysql build would connect to port 3306.

Could you be running two mysql servers on these two ports, each with different user permissions?

Comment: no, I only have MAMP installed. Command line looks like default options because I have MAMP's cli symlinked into `/usr/local/bin/` but there is definitely only one MySQL server installed. Besides, error is not about connection, it's a user access error.

Comment: I know, that's why I asked if you could be running two servers, never meant to suggest you were going to the wrong port.